# Какого управления (падежа) требует слово "догмат"?

Tags: прописная-строчная, управление

> Догмат о вечном блаженстве;
>
> Догмат о Боговоплощении;
>
> Догмат о Промысле Божием...

[Основы духовной культуры (энциклопедический словарь педагога).— Екатеринбург. В.С. Безрукова. 2000.](https://spiritual_culture.academic.ru/704/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5)

---

[Боговоплощение как основа спасения Догмат о воплощении Сына Божия составляет основу и сущность христианства. Это — камень, лежащий во главе угла христианской религии (Мф. 21,42–44).](https://religion.wikireading.ru/184831)

У меня:

> Вообще изобразительное искусство — богохульство в отношении догмата
> Боговоплощения.

---

От Матфея (Мф. 21,42–44) - нужна ли точка? отбивка после 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безусловно, *догмат **о** чём-то.* Или может быть догмат какой-то веры, вероучения, но всё равно о том и сём. Вот пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Или возьмем намеренно самое парадоксальное, «противоречащее» не только науке, но и «здравому смыслу» учение ― например, *догмат христианской веры о непорочном рождении Иисуса Христа девой Марией.* [С. Л. Франк. Религия и наука (1929)]

Отбивка и точка после сокращения нужны: Мф., 21, 42–44. Но бывают и такие варианты: Мф. 21:42-44.

Вот примеры оформления из православного церковного календаря:
*8 июля 2019 г.: Мф., 10 зач., IV, 25 – V, 12;*
*9 июля: Мф., 41 зач., XI, 16–20.*